# CodeIgniter $this->session->set_userdata() on 2 simultaneous AJAX

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter, session

I have  simulatneous AJAX requests on codeIgniter with all of them session update like so:

```
function ajax1($value)
{
    $this->session->set_userdata('foo', $value);
}

function ajax2($value)
{
    $this->session->set_userdata('bar', $value);
}
```

But sometimes because of MySQL concurrency, one variable or the other is not updated, I suppose because one method gets overwrites the new value of the other method with the old value if grabbed from the db.

I cannot update the 2 sessions at the same time as they do completely different things and I don't know which ones will be called, as the page is dynamic and might have one or several of these method calls.

Anybody ran into this in the past and has a way of going around that problem?

Comment: Which version of codeIgniter ?

Comment: Version of CodeIgniter is 2.1.4

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem was fixed in the latest version of codeIgniter, but if you are still using an old one, try to replace system/libraries/Session.php with a new one, or you can just override the Session Library like follow:

application/libraries/MY_Session.php

```
class MY_Session extends CI_Session
{
    function sess_update()
    {
        if (!$this->CI->input->is_ajax_request())
            return parent::sess_update();
    }

}
```

Comment: I thought about updating, but in the changelog I did not see anything about this being fixed: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/changelog.html I guess I'll try updating and see what happens then come back here!

Comment: Well, updating did nothing. I saw in a different solution about overriding the session class but I need to update these sessions in the AJAX, I can't just discard it, I'll try your solution 1 next

Comment: Well I tried all your ideas, there is still session value overwritten

Comment: Are you sure My_session class is used instead of CI_session ? try to print something when sess_update()

Comment: Yes it is, except the line has been commented out in our code: //parent::sess_update(); But I still don't see the point, we need to update the session on AJAX in our methods, so why disable it?